# Android app is installed on OS less than minSDKversion

Tags: android, flutter, crashlytics

I have an android app that is implemented using Flutter. In the app/build.gradle file minSDKversion is set to 23

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "x"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 112
        versionName "0.01.12"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

However, I'm getting some crash reports on Android 4.1.2.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load flutter: findLibrary returned null
```

How the user has installed the app on less than minSDKversion? How is it possible and what can i do?

Comment: Have you followed the guide here https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage?

Comment: Yes. Since I'm using FB Crashlytics, I got notified of such crashes.